# Unable to get implicit intents to work

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm learning how to use implicit intents along with intent filters, and have so far been unable to get the correct activity to fire. The code that is used to fire the intent is:

```
intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.appsculture.intent.action.PLUGIN_RECEIVER");
startActivity(intent);
```

And the Intent filter for the desired activity is:

```
<activity android:name="PluginReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.appsculture.intent.action.PLUGIN_RECEIVER"></action>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The error I get is the standard ActivityNotFound

```
09-04 17:15:27.827: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2552): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.appsculture.intent.action.PLUGIN_RECEIVER }
```

**Solution:** Simply addeded the **android.intent.category.DEFAULT** category to the intent filter

Works like a charm after that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve this by simply adding the android.intent.category.DEFAULT category to the intent filter. Works like a charm after that.

As Commonsware has indicated in a comment on his answer, a category is required for Activities, though not for services or broadcast receivers.

Answer (score 3):

Everything you have there should be fine, though I'd use `new Intent("com.appsculture.intent.action.PLUGIN_RECEIVER")`, and the use of `RECEIVER` seems like an odd piece of an action name for an `Activity` instead of a `BroadcastReceiver`.

If these are in two separate applications, make sure both are installed on your device or emulator, with the latest code (i.e., you didn't make the change and then fail to install the updated app).

Comment: Hi CommonsWare,

I had used your suggested Intent definition earlier (I only switched to intent.setAction because the earlier method kept failing). The result's the same ActivityNotFoundException. Both activities' belong to the same app, hence the issue isn't whether they're updated.

I understand the naming isn't the best, and I'll look to change it. The name was primarily what I felt suited the activity's purpose the best.

Comment: I've posted the solution I found to the problem

Comment: Ah, interesting. For custom actions for services and broadcast receivers, you do not need a category. I forgot that you needed one for activities. My apologies for missing this.